# featureClick won't work in cartoDB

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-js

EDIT: [Link to repo](https://github.com/chrismp/SIPRI-import-export-map-timeline) containing the files. Open the `index.html` file in the `imports` and `exports` folders.

I can get everything except `featurecClick` to work.

My JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var cartoDbTableName = 'sipri_import_export_map_1950_2014';
    var domId = 'map';
    var mapStyle = document.getElementsByClassName('map-style');
    var lat = 0;
    var lon = 0;
    var zoomLvl = 2;
    var options = {
        center: [lat,lon],
        zoom: zoomLvl
    };
    var mapObject = new L.Map(domId,options);
    var layerSource = {
        user_name: 'chrismp',
        type: 'cartodb',
        sublayers: [
            {
                sql: "SELECT * FROM "+cartoDbTableName+" WHERE (gwsyear <= 1950 AND gwsyear > 0)",
                cartocss: mapStyle[0].innerHTML
            }
        ]
    };

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
        .addTo(mapObject);

    cartodb.createLayer(mapObject,layerSource)
        .addTo(mapObject)
        .on('done',function(layer){
                layer.getSubLayer(0).on('featureClick', function(e, latlng, pos, data, subLayerIndex) {
                  console.log(e, latlng, pos, data, subLayerIndex);
                }).on('error',function(err){
                    console.log('featureClick error: '+err);
                });
        }).on('error',function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

The map loads, but I can't actually click any country. What gives?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Are the callback objs in the console.log printed to the console? BTW `subLayerInde` should match `subLayerIndex`

Comment: You might just need to add `layer.getSubLayer(0).setInteraction(true);` http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#sublayersetinteractiontrue

Comment: @AndyEschbacher No errors in the console. I fixed the `subLayerInde` typo. I added `setInteraction(true)`. Still won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the available interactivity columns in your layer:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map,{
          type: "cartodb",
          user_name: userName,
          sublayers: [{
            sql: "SELECT * FROM table",
            cartocss: myCSS,
            interactivity: ['cartodb_id','attribute1','attribute2']
          }]
        })
```

Comment: Hmm, still nothing. To make this a little easier, I've added to my question a link to the Git repo with the files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

To make interactivity work, you need to be sure to include the columns from your datatable that you want to interact with. In your case, it looks like you could be interested in the `gwsyear` column of your data.

You need to alter your code as follows within createLayer:

```
cartodb.createLayer(mapObject,layerSource)
        .addTo(mapObject)
        .on('done',function(layer){
            layer.getSubLayer(0).setInteraction(true);
            layer.getSubLayer(0).setInteractivity('gwsyear'); // need to include at least one column to enable interactivity

            layer.getSubLayer(0).on('featureClick', function(e, latlng, pos, data, subLayerIndex) {
                    console.log(e, latlng, pos, data, subLayerIndex);
                }).on('error',function(err){
                    console.log('featureClick error: '+err);
                });
        }).on('error',function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
```

The difference is the addition of:

```
layer.getSubLayer(0).layer.getSubLayer(0).setInteraction(true);
layer.getSubLayer(0).setInteractivity('gwsyear');
```

If you aren't concerned about which column to include, put in `cartodb_id` instead as it's a more agnostic column.